# Summation and factorial.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, analysis, complex-numbers, generating-functions

If $$2^{n}a_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{a_{k}a_{n-k}},\phantom{a}\forall n\in\mathbb{N},$$ with $a_{0}=1,$ then $$a_{n}=\dfrac{a_{1}^{n}}{n!},\phantom{a}\forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$$

Attempt: Notice that

(1) For $ n=2t + 1, $ we have $$2^{2t+1}a_{2t+1}=2(a_{0}a_{2t+1}+a_{1}a_{2t}+a_{2}a_{2t-1}+\cdots+a_{t-1}a_{t+2}+a_{t}a_{t+1}).$$
Then
\begin{align}
(2^{2t}-1)a_{2t+1}&=a_{1}a_{2t}+a_{2}a_{2t-1}+\cdots+a_{t-1}a_{t+2}+a_{t}a_{t+1}\\
&=a_{1}^{2t+1}\left(\dfrac{1}{(2t)!}+\dfrac{1}{2!(2t-1)!}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{(t-1)!(t+2)!}+\dfrac{1}{t!(t+1)!}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{a_{1}^{2t+1}}{(2t)!}\left(1+\dfrac{2t}{2!}+\cdots+\dfrac{(t+3)(t+4)\cdots(2t-1)(2t)}{(t-1)!}+\dfrac{(t+2)(t+3)(t+4)\cdots(2t-1)(2t)}{t!}\right).
\end{align}

(2) For $n=2t,$ we have $$2^{2t}a_{2t}=2a_{0}a_{2t}+2a_{1}a_{2t-1}+2a_{2}a_{2t-2}+\cdots+2a_{t-1}a_{t+1}+a_{t}^{2}.$$
Then
\begin{align}
2(2^{2t-1}-1)a_{2t}&=2a_{1}a_{2t-1}+2a_{2}a_{2t-2}+\cdots+2a_{t-1}a_{t+1}+a_{t}^{2}\\
&=a_{1}^{2t}\left(\dfrac{2}{(2t-1)!}+\dfrac{2}{2!(2t-2)!}+\cdots+\dfrac{2}{(t-1)!(t+1)!}+\dfrac{1}{t!t!}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{a_{1}^{2t}}{(2t-1)!}\left(2+\dfrac{2(2t-1)}{2!}+\cdots+\dfrac{2(t+2)(t+3)\cdots(2t-1)}{(t-1)!}+\dfrac{(t+1)(t+2)(t+3)\cdots(2t-1)}{t!}\right).
\end{align}

Is there a formula to reduce the above expressions?

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: @RobPratt Do you know any books on these topics? Please!

Comment: Wilf’s *generatingfunctionology* (yes, one word and all lowercase) is a good reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generating function approach in my other answer does not require knowing the desired formula ahead of time, but I understand that you are not familiar with generating functions.  Maybe just treat that answer as an example of why generating functions are useful.

Mathematical induction looks like it would be messy because $n$ appears in both the summand and the upper limit of summation.

Instead, here is an alternative approach.  We have a recurrence relation and a proposed formula.  To prove that the formula is correct, we need only show that it satisfies the recurrence relation.  First check the boundary condition ($n=0$):
$$a_1^0/0! = 1 = a_0,$$
so that checks out.
Now check the main recurrence by substituting the proposed formula:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n a_k a_{n-k} = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_1^k}{k!} \frac{a_1^{n-k}}{(n-k)!} = \frac{a_1^n}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}=\frac{a_1^n}{n!}2^n=2^n a_n,$$
and we are done.

(The sum $\sum_k \binom{n}{k} = 2^n$ is well known and follows from the binomial theorem or by counting subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ according to their cardinality $k$.)

Comment: I have a doubt. What you did was to show that if we take the sequence in that way, we verify the two conditions mentioned above, but if there is another sequence that verifies that, how do I prove it? I don't know if I make myself understood. That succession in that way satisfies the given conditions. My question is: Can there be another one that does it and is different?

Comment: It is a fair question.  The recurrence uniquely defines $a_n$, so if the proposed formula satisfies the recurrence, then it must be equal to $a_n$.  If you prefer a more detailed confirmation of uniqueness, suppose some $b_n$ satisfies the same recurrence, and then show that $a_n-b_n=0$.

Comment: I did what you said before to guarantee the uniqueness of the succession, but I have a doubt. I assumed another sequence that satisfies both conditions. So, I called $ x_{n} $ the difference. My question is: if $ a_{n} $ and $ b_{n} $ satisfy the recurrence, then $ x_{n} $ also, right? I ask him why I used that to get an equation. So, I saw it as the difference to get another equation and I concluded that it was the same sequence. I hope to make myself understood.

Comment: No, if $a_n$ and $b_n$ both satisfy the recurrence, then $x_n=0$.  You can show that by induction.  The first step is $a_0=b_0=1$, so $x_0=1-1=0$.

Comment: $2^{n}x_{n}=2^{n}(a_{n}-b_{n})=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{(a_{k}a_{n-k}-b_{k}b_{n-k})};$ and $2^{n}x_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{x_{k}x_{n-k}}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{(a_{k}a_{n-k}+b_{k}b_{n-k})}-\sum_{k=0}^{n}{(a_{k}b_{n-k}+b_{k}a_{n-k})};$ are they true?

Answer (score 0):

The sum is a convolution of $a_n$ with itself, so the generating function of the RHS is $A(z)^2$, where $A(z)=\sum_n a_n z^n$ is the generating function of $a_n$. The generating function of $2^n a_n$ is $A(2z)$, so we have $A(2z)=A(z)^2$.  Hence $A(z)=\exp(c z)$ for some constant $c$, which implies that $a_n=c^n/n!$. Now evaluate at $n=1$ to obtain $a_1=c^1/1!=c$, so $a_n=a_1^n/n!$.

Comment: I do not know what you're talking about. That is, I have not seen that concept of generating function. Could you give me more details of what you said above? Please!

Comment: That is what I must conclude with what I just asked, but first I must prove it. We were told that it can be proved by mathematical induction, but it is complicated.

Comment: That c mentioned above will be the $ a_{1} $ of the question I asked earlier. I must show that there is a $ \lambda \in \mathbb {R} $. My question is: can I take $ a_{n} = \dfrac {| a_{1} |^ {n}} {n!}$ and the argument is still true, right? Even when I must show uniqueness. I thought about that at the last minute, since $ (a_{n})$ is a complex succession.

Comment: What is $\lambda$? All the $a_n$ are rational numbers because $a_0=1$ is rational, and $a_n$ is a rational function of previous $a_m$'s with $m<n$.